# Choosing a random image with a click via JFrame application

Tags: java, image, swing, random

I'm very new to Java, and need some help creating my random image picker.

My code so far:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameMain extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private String []images = { "010.png", "011.png", "012.png", "019-a.png", "020-a.png", "021.png", "022.png",
            "025.png", "026-a.png", "027-a.png", "028-a.png", "035.png", "036.png", "037-a.png", "038-a.png",
            "039.png", "040.png", "041.png", "042.png", "046.png", "047.png", "050.png", "051.png",
            "052-a.png", "053-a.png", "054.png", "055.png", "056.png", "057.png", "058.png", "059.png",
            "060.png", "061.png", "062.png", "063.png", "064.png", "065.png", "066.png", "067.png", "068.png",
            "072.png", "073.png", "074-a.png", "075-a.png", "076-a.png", "079.png", "080.png", "081.png",
            "082.png", "088-a.png", "089-a.png", "090.png", "091.png", "092.png", "093.png", "094.png",
            "096.png", "097.png", "102.png", "103-a.png", "104.png", "105-a.png", "113.png", "115.png",
            "118.png", "119.png", "120.png", "121.png", "123.png", "125.png", "126.png", "127.png", "128.png",
            "129.png", "130.png", "131.png", "132.png", "133.png", "134.png", "135.png", "136.png", "137.png",
            "142.png", "143.png", "147.png", "148.png", "149.png", "165.png", "166.png", "167.png", "168.png",
            "169.png", "170.png", "171.png", "172.png", "173.png", "174.png", "185.png", "186.png", "196.png",
            "197.png", "198.png", "199.png", "200.png", "209.png", "210.png", "212.png", "215.png", "222.png",
            "225.png", "227.png", "233.png", "235.png", "239.png", "240.png", "241.png", "242.png", "278.png",
            "279.png", "283.png", "284.png", "296.png", "297.png", "299.png", "302.png", "318.png", "319.png",
            "320.png", "321.png", "324.png", "327.png", "328.png", "329.png", "330.png", "339.png", "340.png",
            "349.png", "350.png", "351.png", "359.png", "361.png", "362.png", "369.png", "370.png", "371.png",
            "372.png", "373.png", "374.png", "375.png", "376.png", "408.png", "409.png", "410.png", "411.png",
            "422.png", "433.png", "425.png", "426.png", "429.png", "430.png", "438.png", "440.png", "443.png",
            "444.png", "445.png", "446.png", "447.png", "448.png", "456.png", "457.png", "461.png", "462.png",
            "466.png", "467.png", "470.png", "471.png", "474.png", "476.png", "478.png", "506.png", "507.png",
            "508.png", "524.png", "525.png", "526.png", "546.png", "547.png", "548.png", "549.png", "551.png",
            "552.png", "553.png", "564.png", "565.png", "566.png", "567.png", "568.png", "569.png", "582.png",
            "583.png", "584.png", "584.png", "587.png", "594.png", "627.png", "628.png", "629.png", "630.png",
            "661.png", "662.png", "663.png", "674.png", "675.png", "700.png", "703.png", "704.png", "705.png",
            "706.png", "707.png", "708.png", "709.png", "718.png", "722.png", "723.png", "724.png", "725.png",
            "726.png", "727.png", "728.png", "729.png", "730.png", "731.png", "732.png", "733.png", "734.png",
            "735.png", "736.png", "737.png", "738.png", "739.png", "740.png", "741.png", "741-p.png",
            "741-pau.png", "741-s.png", "742.png", "743.png", "744.png", "745.png", "745-m.png", "746.png",
            "746-s.png", "747.png", "748.png", "749.png", "750.png", "751.png", "752.png", "753.png",
            "754.png", "755.png", "756.png", "757.png", "758.png", "759.png", "760.png", "761.png", "762.png",
            "763.png", "764.png", "765.png", "766.png", "767.png", "768.png", "769.png", "770.png", "771.png",
            "772.png", "773.png", "774.png", "775.png", "776.png", "777.png", "778.png", "779.png", "780.png", 
            "781.png", "782.png", "783.png", "784.png", "785.png", "786.png", "787.png", "788.png", "789.png",
            "790.png", "791.png", "792.png", "793.png", "794.png", "795.png", "796.png", "797.png", "798.png",
            "799.png", "800.png", "801.png" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrameMain frame = new JFrameMain();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public JFrameMain() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblPhoto = new JLabel("");
    lblPhoto.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(128, 0, 128)));
    lblPhoto.setBounds(21, 11, 391, 227);
    contentPane.add(lblPhoto);

    Timer timer = new Timer(800, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int n = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
            String image = images[n];
            lblPhoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\images\\" + image));
        }
    });
    timer.start();

    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so that, say when I press MOUSE1, the images start rolling, then after say 3 seconds, lands on an image.

And then on the press of another button it would repeat.

Any help is greatly appreciated. (As I said, never done anything close to this before)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Don't expect other users to write code for you, try by yourself, show your effort and post your code. :)

Comment: @ema.jar I did, it's at the top.

Comment: Your question remains somewhat vague. I've tried to answer it, but can only give general recommendations. If you need further help then please ask for clarification and also show what you've tried and tell us how it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

General suggestions:

- Read the images in once at program start up, and not within the Timer's ActionListener, and store them in a collection, probably an ArrayList of Image or ImageIcon.
- In the Timer's ActionListener swap ImageIcons, but again don't re-read in the images unnecessarily.
- You've too many key variables declared in the constructor and thus invisible (out of scope) of the rest of the class. Get the Timer's declaration and the image-displaying JLabel out of the constructor, and make them instance fields in the class.
- In your JButton's ActionListener start the Timer, one that randomly changes the images every xxx milliseconds.
- In the same Timer's ActionListener, have it stop after 3 seconds are up, either by repeating the timer until a count reaches a value obtaiend from dividing 3000 by the millisecond delay, or else use delta system time to check for 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).